# empty JaxbSmlPart in newest versions of xlsx4j

Tags: docx4j

I hope somebody can give me a hint to solve this problem:
After a java upgrade to 11 and docx4j upgrade to 11.1.3 (tried 8.1.3 as an alternative with same result) I can't get the content of the SharedStrings part of xlsx files. This happens even with the sample files (VariableReplace or PartsList, e.g.).

Here's the code I used to evaluate the problem. It's taken from the VariableReplace sample file:

```
SpreadsheetMLPackage opcPackagepkg = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(new File(inputfilepath));
System.out.println("\n\nPART TYPE\n\n:" + opcPackagepkg.getParts().get(new PartName("/xl/sharedStrings.xml")).toString());   // gives correct type "org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.SpreadsheetML.SharedStrings@79518e00"
JaxbSmlPart smlPart = (JaxbSmlPart)opcPackagepkg.getParts().get(new PartName("/xl/sharedStrings.xml"));
System.out.println("\n\nBEFORE sml\n:" + smlPart.getXML());    // smlPart.getXML() gives null as result

// and so, of course, the following ends with an exception:
HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<String, String>();
mappings.put("title1", "This is a title");
smlPart.variableReplace(mappings);   // ends with an NullPointerException
```

I tried several Excel files just to be sure to not have a corrupted one. Everytime same result.
I also unzipped the Excel files to view the /xl/sharedStrings.xml file. 
I even tried to use the line

```
JaxbSmlPart smlPart = (JaxbSmlPart)opcPackagepkg.getParts().get(new PartName("/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"));
```

but this gives me the correct result to be a WorkSheetPart (which correctly results in an docx4j exception then because it's not a SharedStrings part).

Any ideas where I'm wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
    SharedStrings ss = xlsxPkg.getWorkbookPart().getSharedStrings();
    System.out.println(ss.getPartName().getName());
    System.out.println(ss.getXML());
```